# Check if record exists with multiple conditions else insert in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado

I've written procedure as below to check for the record of day and slot combination with teacher or classroom or (specific standard and Division) as below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procCreateSchedule]
    (@classId INT, 
     @dayId INT, 
     @slotId INT, 
     @standardId INT, 
     @divisionId INT, 
     @subjectId INT, 
     @teacherId INT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM schedules_test
                   WHERE day = @dayId
                     AND slot = @slotId
                     AND standard = @standardId
                     AND division = @divisionId) 
    ELSE
       IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM schedules_test
                      WHERE day = @dayId
                        AND slot = @slotId
                        AND teacherId = @teacherId)
       ELSE
          IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM schedules_test
                         WHERE day = @dayId
                           AND slot = @slotId
                           AND classroom = @classId)
          ELSE
          BEGIN
              INSERT INTO schedules_test (classroom, day, slot, standard, division, subject, teacherId) 
              VALUES (@classId, @dayId, @slotId, @standardId, @divisionId, @subjectId, @teacherId)
          END
      END
```

But it seems it's not working. Please can anyone suggest how can I check multiple conditions before inserting with help of if else or is there any other approach to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn all your conditions into one `WHERE` clause in one `SELECT` statement:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM scheduled_tests
    WHERE day=@dayId AND slot=@slotId AND 
          (classroom=@classId  OR teacherId OR standard=@standardId AND division=@divisionId)
)

 ....
```

But really, if you can, don't write stored procedures. Add this logic to your C# code, it will be a lot easier to maintain by everybody reading the code in the future.

Comment: I totally disagree. Stored procedures are a great tool, and they are easier to change when needed since you don't need to recompile your code.

Comment: They're not part of your code, which means you have a big mess on your hands. *ESPECIALLY* if you change one without running all your tests again. Unless there's a performance issue that can't be resolved otherwise, stay away from stored procedures, and don't let your DBA convince you otherwise.

Comment: Wrong. Stored procedures **are** a part of my code. My code spreads over database, server and client. If you know what you are doing, there's no good reason to avoid stored procedures. Otherwise it's just like using a Suzuki Ninja with training wheels.

Answer (score 1):

Don't check this at the application layer.  You are subject to race conditions -- two different threads inserting the same data.  Both can succeed.

Instead, create unique indexes so the *database* validates the data.  The unique indexes should be on:

- `schedules_test(day, slot, standard, division)`
- `schedules_test(day, slot, teacherid)`
- `schedules_test(day, slot, classid)`

(Note:  the order of the keys does not matter.)

Then, the body of the stored procedure can use `try`/`catch`:

```
begin try
    insert into schedules_test(classroom, day, slot, standard, division, subject, teacherId) 
        values (@classId, @dayId, @slotId, @standardId, @divisionId, @subjectId, @teacherId);
end try
begin catch
    . . .
end catch;
```

Comment: With the proper constraints on the data, only one will succeed and the other will fail. The more logic you put in your application code - the better it is for someone to understand that logic.

Comment: Why use try...catch for something that can be verified in code? Isn't [hinting UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK good enough](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I created all the three unique keys as suggested designed the stored procedure as

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . Simple: race conditions.  It is better to do the checking in the database.  Databases are designed to maintain data integrity.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree it should be a stored procedure, and I also agree there should be those unique constraints (or indexes). The link in my comment goes to an article by Dan Guzman, describing a way to avoid race conditions by using these lock hints. So, if using the lock hints avoids the race condition, why not use them instead of a try...catch block?

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . I think it is still better to have the database maintain data integrity.

Comment: but using these lock hints still keeps the database in charge, it just eliminates the need for the try...catch, doesn't it?